# Static struct with static members

Tags: c++, static, struct

Today I found myself creating a static array of 2 ints, and because its inline initalization is not allowed in C++ (not C++11), I reverted to using a static variable of type struct.

```
class MyWidget {
  ...
  static const struct Margin {
    const int horizontal = 1;
    const int vertical = 1;
  } margin;

};
```

I noticed that internal variables are used only once for all instances of struct Margin, so I decided to make them static too.

```
class MyWidget {
  ...
  static const struct Margin {
    static const int horizontal = 1;
    static const int vertical = 1;
  } margin;

};
```

What wonders me is the difference between declaring a static struct variable vs. a static struct variable with static members. AFAC static objects are allocated only once in memory, therefore Margin struct wil be allocated only once no matter if my members are static or not.

Do I miss something? Does there exist a difference or is it a mere syntactic sugar?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "static struct" in C++, static is a storage-class-specifier and applies to variables or functions, not types.

Comment: You should not revert back to using a struct with named members instead an array of unnamed elements.. it should be the other way around..

Comment: I've googled for a bit, and I can't seem to find meaningful results about "static structs". Are you perhaps coming from the C# world?

Comment: OP is plainly asking about members of a struct defined as the type of a static member of a class, and whether there's any difference if the struct's members are also static.

Comment: @Chowlett that isn't clear. Other languages have static classes. OP might be under the impression that C++ has them too.

Comment: @PlasmaHH you're write. This is what I meant, a static const variable of type struct Margin.

Comment: @Antonijn I am not, that is why I also searched for static structs, but having found nothing decided to post my question here. The correct title would be not a static struct, but a static variable of type struct Margin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about "static structs", because in C++, there are no such things as static structs (as opposed to languages like C#, where static classes are a workaround for the fact that there are no global functions).

What you're doing, is creating an instance of that class, and making the **instance** (`margin`) static (and constant). So your struct is not static, you are simply defining a struct, and making a `static const` instance of it, belonging to `MyWidget`. The difference between the two given examples now, should be quite obvious.

In the first example, you're creating a static variable called margin, belonging to `MyWidget`, meaning you can access the `horizontal` member like so

```
MyWidget::margin.horizontal
```

Where `margin` is the instance you have created.

Whereas if you made the members of the struct static, you would not be able to do that. Instead, you would have to access them like so:

```
MyWidget::Margin::horizontal
```

Where `Margin` is the `struct`. Note however, that in the second case, there is no need for the static instance `margin`, since it has no instance fields associated with it.

Comment: so in the second case I can drop `static const struct Margin {...} margin;` and refer simply to `const struct Margin {...} margin;`?

Comment: @PavloDyban Then `margin` would be an instance variable, which means you need an instance of `MyWidget` for it to be able to work.

Answer (score 7):

There is indeed a difference:

```
class MyWidget {
  ...
  static const struct Margin {
    const int horizontal = 1;
    const int vertical = 1;
  } margin;


  void foo() {
    Margin anotherMargin = { 3, 4 };
  }
};
```

This creates another instance of Margin, having different members. The `static` in `static const struct Margin {...} margin;` applies to the variable `margin`, not to the class/struct `Margin`. That means there is only one Margin object shared by all MyWidget objects, but you can very well create other Margin objects having different values. The above code would not compile with `horizontal` and `vertical` being static themselves, because then a Margin object would hav no member variables (statics are no real members) and therefore all Margin objects would share the `horizontal` and `vertical` values.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are significant differences. In the both cases you declare `MyWidget::margin` that is of type `MyWidget::Margin` and they are static. In first case `margin` is an object that has two fields, `horizontal` and `vertical`. In second case, `margin` is an object with no fields and you could just drop that object.

In the first case you need to use form `margin.vertical` (or `MyWidget::margin.vertical` if accessing from outside `MyWidget`) to access the fields, in second case, you can do it like this `Margin::vertical` (or `MyWidget::Margin::vertical`).

Comment: why is `margin` in the second case an object with no fields? aren't static variables somehow linked to the struct? `struct Margin` must know where to fetch the values of horizontal and vertical when I call `Margin::vertical`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Static fields are not part of object. You can think of static fields of Margin as if they were global variables in a namespace.

Comment: This is it! I got it now. Because static variables are the same across all instances, I kept thinking about pointers replacing these variables, but I have forgotten about global vars. Thx!