# Why is static struct allowed by the compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

According to [this questions's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976971/static-struct-with-static-members), there is no such thing as a `static struct` in C++. However I was refactoring code:

```
static struct _MyStruct
{
 int x;
}MyStruct;
```

And accidentally ended up with:

```
static struct _MyStruct
{
 int x;
};

static _MyStruct MyStruct;
```

I was surprised to see that it compiles (VS2019, C++17) and in my experience the compiler doesn't let you add keywords that mean nothing - so *does* it do anything or is left there for compatibility reasons?

Comment: That might be one of the many *particularities* of MSVC.

Comment: gcc/clang/msvc reject that code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/cz9nGW) (as expected).

Comment: what confuses me a little is that the answer you link explains that objects can be static (as opposed to types) and thats what changed between the two versions of your code. So assuming the first was fine, why shouldnt be the second?

Comment: `_Mystruct` is a name reserved for the implementation. The suppressed warning might be intentional, so as not to give warnings on its own headers. Using it in your own code is **Undefined Behavior** - a missing warning is a very benign outcome.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 no, I am declaring my type is static as well in v2. Which seems to be a non-feature.

Comment: yes, the first part is the same, so why should it not compile in the second when it did in the first. is it possible that you are missing a keyword `struct` somewhere?

Comment: Do you have your warning levels turned on?  `warning C4091: 'static ': ignored on left of 'MyStruct' when no variable is declared`  Appears that the standard allows `static` there, and ignores it.

Comment: @Eljay `Appears that the standard allows static there` Nope.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard says (quote from latest draft):

> [dcl.stc]
>
> The static specifier shall be applied only to the declaration of a variable or function, to a structured binding declaration ([dcl.struct.bind]), or to the declaration of an anonymous union ([class.union.anon]).

So, the latter example is ill-formed.

Compilers are required to diagnose ill-formed programs (except when standard says otherwise). They are not required to fail compilation. Compiling an ill-formed program is typically a language extension.

> so does it do anything

Sometimes to learn what a language extension does, best way is to read the documentation of the compiler. Other times, it is simpler to compile and see what the compiler says:

> ```
> <source>(4): warning C4091: 'static ': ignored on left of '_MyStruct' when no variable is declared
> ```

Conclusion: No, it doesn't do anything.